# Guice - multiple persistence providers using same connection per transaction

Tags: java, persistence, guice, jooq

I have two persistence providers I like to use - my own JDBC approach (DBAccess), and jooq (DSLContext).  A DSLContext and my DBAccess both can be created using a Connection and some configuration details. I'm trying to convert a project to use Guice, and would like to create a DAO that has the ability to use both in one transaction, e.g.

```
class ThingDAO {
    final DBAccess dbAccess;
    final DSLContext dslContext;

    @Inject
    ThingDAO(DBAccess dbAccess, DSLContext dslContext) {
        this.dbAccess = dbAccess;
        this.dslContext = dslContext;
    }

    Thing getThingForId(int id) {
        return dslContext.select().from(OBJECT)....
    }

    void save(Thing t) {
        dbAccess.save(t);
    }

    Stuff joinThingToStuffTableAndGetStuff(Thing t) {
    // the Stuff I get may depend on what has been saved so far, so I need 
    // the dslContext and dbAccess operating on the same connection

        dslContext....
    }
}
```

which I could then use along the lines of

```
@Transactional
doTheThings(int id, int[] data) {
    ThingDAO dao = thingDaoProvider.get();
    Thing t = dao.getThingForId(id);
    t.doTheThings(data);
    dao.save(t);
    Stuff s = dao.joinThingToStuffTableAndGetStuff(t);
    ....
}
```

I've been looking at [this guice extension for jooq](https://github.com/supercargo/guice-persist-jooq), which makes me think I want something along the lines of a UnitOfWork that grabs a connection from my datasource in order to give to a DBAccess and a DSLContext, but I'm unsure if that's right or how to proceed even if it is.